# Bash script to convert special characters found in XML file to HTML Decimal Entities

Tags: xml, bash, bulkupdate

I have several XML files (same filename, different folders) containing data and some of that data contains special characters, diacritics, accents, etc. I am trying to parse these files through a python script someone else wrote that will convert and combine all of that data into a single excel spreadsheet using xlsxwriter with a separate worksheet for each file. However, the python script it is getting hung up on all the special characters and exiting each time it encounters one. So I am looking for bash script (or rather macOS's zshell) a way to parse these files before hand and replace "en masse" each of those special characters, for example...

From this:

```
<0xa0>
ï
è
é
em dash
left double quote
right double quote
non-breaking space
etc.
```

and convert to this:

```
&#32;
&#207;
&#232;
&#233;
&#8212;
&#8220;
&#8221;
&#160;
etc.
```

I've just been doing manual find/replace in sublime text but this is becoming very tedious!

Comment: a sed script like `s/<0xa0>/\&#32;/g; s/.../../g; ....' file > outFile` would do the trick and easy enough to code if you have a perfectly matched list of pairs, ideally in the same file. Some of the inputs may need escaping to avoid regex and capture group syntax. Post that data and someone will likely help. You would also have to arrange lists so they don't recursively substitute. (hmm). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As a close answer, just passing the file to `xmllint` will return HTML hex entities provided that it has NO encoding declaration.
**See at the end of this answer** a version that ouputs decimal encoding by adding text processing.

Given this file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <child>
    ñ
    á
    í 
    ë
</child>
<child>
    some ascii text mixed with utf-8 characters
    spanish ñ aacute á  euro €  ~  þ
    more text — “ ”  registered ®
</child>
</root>
```

Just passing the file

```
xmllint --format tmp.xml
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <child>
    &#xF1;
    &#xE1;
    &#xED; 
    &#xEB;
</child>
  <child>
    some ascii text mixed with utf-8 characters
    spanish &#xF1; aacute &#xE1;  euro &#x20AC;  ~  &#xFE;
    more text &#x2014; &#x201C; &#x201D;  registered &#xAE;
</child>
</root>
```

For XML files with encoding set, remove it before passing to `xmllint` and add it back after

```
sed -re 's/(<\?xml .* )encoding=".*"( .*)?(\?>)/\1\2\3/' tmp.xml |\
xmllint - |\
sed -re 's/(<\?xml .*)(\?>)/\1 encoding="UTF-8"\2/'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child>
    &#xF1;
    &#xE1;
    &#xED; 
    &#xEB;
</child>
<child>
    some ascii text mixed with utf-8 characters
    spanish &#xF1; aacute &#xE1;  euro &#x20AC;  ~  &#xFE;
    more text &#x2014; &#x201C; &#x201D;  registered &#xAE;
</child>
</root>
```

To avoid generating entities if file has no `encoding`

```
xmllint --format --encode 'UTF-8' tmp.xml
```

**To generate decimal encoding**

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='|' read pat val; do
   if grep -q '¬' <<<"${val}" ; then
     printf "$pat\n" $(tr '¬' ' ' <<<"${val}")
   else
     printf "$pat\n" "${val}"
   fi
done < <(xmllint tmp.xml | sed -re '/\&#/! s/.*/%s|&/; :a; /\&#/ s/(\&#)x([A-F0-9]+);(.*)/\1%d;\3¬0x\2/ ;ta ; /¬/ s/([^¬]+)¬(.*)/\1|\2/')
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <child>
    &#241;
    &#225;
    &#237; 
    &#235;
</child>
<child>
    some ascii text mixed with utf-8 characters
    spanish &#241; aacute &#225;  euro &#8364;  ~  &#254;
    more text &#8212; &#8220; &#8221;  registered &#174;
</child>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [the proper Perl's module](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities):

```
$ cat file
ï
è
é
'
"
```

```
$ perl -CSAD -MHTML::Entities -pe 'HTML::Entities::encode_numeric($_)' file
&#xEF;
&#xE8;
&#xE9;
&#x27;
&#x22;
```

Comment: But that would encode the whole file not just text inside elements, correct? That's what recode did `cat tmp.xml | recode ..html
&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;`

Comment: You need to parse the DOM to pass the function only on text you choose

Comment: Installed xmllint and am giving this a go...it is encountering parse errors on the – (em-dash) and ® (registered) symbols so far...